# With httpPut to skip that column if .net core is null or null

Tags: c#, .net, linq, asp.net-core, microservices

I am developing micro-service with .NET Core.
The following code is working with an `HttpPut` request.
But if any field has empty or null value in our incoming JSON request, I want it to retrieve the previous value.

**I don't want to constantly run the code below. Is there a short way around this?**

```cs
if(updateCustomer.Surname != null && updateCustomer.Surname !=string.Empty)
{
    customer.Surname = updateCustomer.Surname;
}

var serviceResponse = new ServiceResponse<GetCustomerDto>();
Customer customer = await _context.Customers.FirstOrDefaultAsync(c => c.Id == updateCustomer.Id);

var persons = (from p in  _context.Customers where p.Id == updateCustomer.Id select p);
foreach (var person in persons)
{
    person.Name = updateCustomer.Name;
    person.Surname = updateCustomer.Surname;
    person.BusinessCode = "123";
    person.Phone = updateCustomer.Phone;
}
await _context.SaveChangesAsync();

serviceResponse.Data = _mapper.Map<GetCustomerDto>(customer);
```

Comment: It sounds like you are looking for a code idiom to make your code more readable. Is that correct? If so, for nullable types, there is [`GetValueOrDefault()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.nullable-1.getvalueordefault?view=net-5.0). For types that do not have that method, you could create an extension method or simply a method that determines its return value by whether a parameter is null.

Comment: yes mate. But can you show this with an example?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following the `GetValueOrDefault()` idiom from [Nullable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.nullable-1?view=net-5.0) types, you can create a string extension method to select between two values like so:

```
public static class StringExtensions 
{
    public static string GetValueOrDefault(this string str, string alternative)
    {
        if(string.IsNullOrEmpty(str))
        {
            return alternative;
        }
        
        return str;
    }   
}

public class Program
{
    public class Person 
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string Surname { get; set; }
        public string BusinessCode { get; set; }
        public string Phone { get; set; }
    }
    
    public static void Main()
    {
        Person previous = new Person
        {
            Name = null,
            Surname = "Smith",
            BusinessCode = "123",
            Phone = "(555) 123-4567"
        };
        
        Person current = new Person
        {
            Name = "John",
            Surname = string.Empty,
            BusinessCode = "321",
            Phone = "(555) 765-4321"
        };
        
        Person updated = new Person
        {
            Name = current.Name.GetValueOrDefault(previous.Name),
            Surname = current.Surname.GetValueOrDefault(previous.Surname),
            BusinessCode = current.BusinessCode.GetValueOrDefault(previous.BusinessCode),
            Phone = current.Phone.GetValueOrDefault(previous.Phone)
        };
    }
}
```